# Difference between "ink_primitives::AccountId" and just default "AccountId" type

Tags: ink, accountid

I try to solve Rust's error that I included below:

```
    = note: expected struct `Mapping<ink::ink_primitives::AccountId, u128>`
            found reference `&Mapping<ink::ink_primitives::AccountId, u128, ResolverKey<AutoKey, ManualKey<3381773259>>>`
```

And I am not sure that, I correctly assign type to `token1_balance` variable like:

`token1_balance: Mapping<AccountId, Balance>,`

In the [ink_primitives documentation](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_primitives/struct.AccountId.html) is written:

> This is a mirror of the AccountId type used in the default configuration of PALLET contracts.

And I do not know if `ink::ink_primitives::AccountId` are exactly the same like default `AccountId` or not? [Here](https://github.com/TomaszWaszczyk/ink-automated-market-maker/blob/master/automated_market_maker/lib.rs#L28) is the wider context of the question.

Comment: Problem is not with `AccountId` type, it's with the use of ` _balance: Mapping<AccountId, Balance>` parameter in your `valid_amount_check()` method.
Your mapping type is using `AutoKey` and thus key will be generated on compile time which we can see is `ManualKey<3381773259>`, so you can't hardcode that to use as a type for argument.

Simple solution, do not pass `Mapping<>`  (which use `AutoKey`) as argument to a function.